# Can an LLVM Pass be used to change code?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a program optimization, which involves adding new functions, removing lines of code, inserting function calls and changing arguments to functions.

Is all this possible using an LLVM Pass, and if yes how would I write such a code for this?

Having had a look at the how to write an LLVM pass page on the LLVM website, it does not explain anything about altering code.

Comment: Yes, although some of these things are not trivial.  I have added / replaced existing functions and done so.  But overall, this question may be too broad for a single stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Brian do you have any example passes for adding/removing functions which i can use to learn?

Comment: Yes, I have a pass that does this - [Contech.cpp](https://github.com/bprail/contech/blob/master/llvm-contech/Contech.cpp) : createMicroTaskWrapStruct.  This function injects a new function into the IR and is invoked from [Contech.h](https://github.com/bprail/contech/blob/master/llvm-contech/Contech.h), where the LLVM pass has to replace the existing function call and its arguments with a call to the new function.  I will admit that this published research and not a toy example, so it may be somewhat opaque to read.  And for that I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html) is a really good guide to start off writing pass. It also has an example how to change code.